# zip xlsx file not opening on pycharm instead its duplicating (MACBOOK)

Tags: python, pycharm, python-zipfile

I encountered an issue while working on my Python project in PyCharm. I started by creating an Excel sheet containing product IDs and prices. After saving the file within my PyCharm project, I utilized the 'openpyxl' library to import the Excel data. Subsequently, I implemented code which I'll provide below to perform price corrections and saved the modified file as a new version within the project. However, when attempting to open the ZIP file containing the XLSX file, it unexpectedly duplicates the file instead of displaying the intended modifications. The duplication problem seems to occur after performing the price corrections and saving the new file. I am unsure why this duplication is happening and seek assistance to resolve the issue. I also tried to open the original file and the same issue occurs.

Below is the code I used to import and implement the price corrections which works fine however I want to be able to actually view my new file.

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
cell = sheet.cell(1, 1)

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, 3)
    corrected_price = cell.value * 0.9
    corrected_price_cell = sheet.cell(row, 4)
    corrected_price_cell.value = corrected_price

wb.save('transactions2.xlsx')
```

When opening the transactions2.xlsx file it creates a file called transactions2.xlsx.cpgz. I don't know if this is an issue with my Macs archive utility or something else so any help is appreciated.